# How best to rearrange the order of the address fields on the New individual/contact from?

Tags: fields, html

I'd like to play with order and layout of the address fields on the New Individual form.  I understand that in the localisation setting s this can be achieved but I am not having any luck with the for a NEW individual/contact.  Is there not a .php file that i can edit the HTML output and manually rearrange the order of the fields?  Is this the best approach? Thanks, Joe.

Comment: Just checking. Do you understand that the New Individual is a 'profile' and that you can therefore change the order via the UI

Comment: It's ambiguous. "new individual" is both a profile, and it's also a core form. OP may be referring to `http://yoursite.org/civicrm/contact/add?ct=Individual`. @jkobier can you edit your question to be more specific about what you want to do?

Comment: based on the comment to ErikH's answer yes, it is referring to http://somesite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fadd&reset=1&ct=Individual so my point about it being a Profile is incorrect, though am left uncertain why Joe couldn't be using a Profile for what he needs

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you create a little jQuery to move the fields around (something like you see here: [template jQuery example](https://github.com/CiviCooP/be.aivl.zipcodes/blob/master/templates/CRM/Contact/Form/Edit/postcode_contact_js.tpl))

And then place the created template with jQuery on the appropriate form (which will probably be `CRM_Contact_Form_Edit_Address`) using the alterContent hook (something like what you see here: [alterContext hook example](https://github.com/CiviCooP/be.aivl.zipcodes/blob/master/zipcodes.php#L116)

Although this is not exactly what you want, it shows the approach. Does that help or is the confusion only growing?

Comment: Confusion = increasing!
To clarify what I am trying to do...
I want to hide some fields and re-order some fields on the New Contact form/page:
http://somesite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fadd&reset=1&ct=Individual
I was hopng to do this via the UI but there does not appear to be a profile available that matches the fields on this page. Failing that surely there is a file hidden in the application somewhere that I can use to comment out or delete fields and move others around...?

Comment: There is, my approach simply means you do not have to re-do that at every upgrade?

Comment: Sorry ErikH - what do you mean by "there is my approach"?  Where is it - am I missing something?

Comment: I mean the approach of creating an extension and using the alterContent hook

Answer (score 0):

What you need could potentially be delivered purely by creating, or modifying, a Profile.